# Parse JSON array to table in Splunk

Tags: splunk-query

I need some help in getting JSON array parsed into a table in splunk. Have below JSON data in splunk

```
data="[

{
 'environment':test,
 'name':Java,
 'date':28-01-2018
},

{
 'environment':prod,
 'name':Javascript,
 'date':28-01-2019
}

]"
```

I am expecting an output as

```
*******************************
Environment | name | date
*******************************
test        | Java | 28-01-2018

prod        | Javascript | 28-01-2019
```

Appreciate any help.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Looks you have to modify you log to have proper JSON structure.
After that you can use `spath` command to interpret and get the values from JSON.  here is the sample solution

```
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="data=\"[{\"environment\":\"test\",\"name\":\"Java\",\"date\":\"28-01-2018\"},{\"environment\":\"prod\",\"name\":\"Javascript\",\"date\":\"28-01-2019\"}]\""
| rex field=_raw "data=\"(?<data>.*)\""
| spath input=data
| table {}.date, {}.environment, {}.name
```

Answer (score -2):

It should be fairly simple using *spath*

```
your search base |spath input=data
```